# Get a count number out of {{each teams}}

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm running a {{#each teams}} that's dynamically sorted in my html and am trying to get a counter that will run each time it can be ranked from 1-10.
How do I do that? I am trying to add a var counter, but no idea where it can be placed to work. =( Trying to get the {{rank}} to run from 1-10.

```html
{{#each teams}}
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">{{rank}}</td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{points}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Update: Thanks David Weldon, I'm checking, trying out the answer given on the post!

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: Are you asking how to animate counting, as in changing the `rank` value from 0 to 1, then from 1 to 2, and so on, until it gets to the final `rank` value?

Comment: Let's say there's 10 teams. And I sort them by points to be displayed.
I want its accompanying rank to show from 1 to 10 accordingly basically.